# What's the location on Coruscant we've seen that's farthest from the Jedi Temple?

Tags: star-wars, coruscant

It seems like most of what we see of Coruscant in the Canon Star Wars films and TV shows takes place within the [Federal District](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Federal_District), which includes the Senate Building, the Executive Building, and the Jedi Temple. Even in works that take place in the underbelly of the city-planet, it doesn't seem like the action takes place too far (horizontally speaking) from these known locations.

Has any official work shown a location on Coruscant as far away as the other side of the planet from the Federal District? And if not, what's the farthest location we've seen? (Legends and Canon answers are both accepted!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some of the action in [*Star Wars - Coruscant Nights I: Jedi Twilight*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Coruscant_Nights_I:_Jedi_Twilight) takes place in the Factory District. It's noted that this place is on the opposite side of the planet from Galactic City, where the Jedi Temple (and Senate, etc) are based.

> A few minutes later, **he realized Xizor's destination: the Antipodes. The area of the globe diametrically opposite to Imperial City. The area known as the Factory District.**
>
> A chill ran the down on his arms and neck. The Factory District was,
> according to all accounts, one of the most dangerous places on the
> entire planet. Centuries ago, it had been a thriving industrial center
> that sprawled over most of the northeastern quadrisphere, near the
> equator. But economic downturns and the streamlining of production
> techniques on Metellos, Brentaal, Duro, and other Core worlds,
> together with the lifting of trade sanctions and political lobbying in
> the Galactic Senate, had resulted in most of the manufacturing and
> engineering contracts being moved offworld. As a result, except for
> isolated areas where automated minimal production of some goods still
> took place, thousands of square kilometers had become forgotten, and
> eventually cut off from utilities, supplies, and communications. The
> area was a wasteland now, more lawless and dangerous even than areas
> like the Southern Underground or the Invisible Sector. By day,
> primitive tribes of humans and other species roamed the dilapidated
> structures; by night the ruins were prowled by Cthons, stratts, and,
> some averred, by nameless horrors unknown on any other world.

---

In the main canon the farthest we see from the centre of Galactic City (excluding space shots) is about a two or three 'sectors' away from the Temple district, when Dooku and Palpatine visit [*The Works*](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/The_Works) in Sector 943.

[image]

Comment: I read that book and had still forgotten that any of it takes place that far from the Temple. Nice find!